# How do I refactor this Vue Js code to avoid using local storage?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage, auth0

I have a code that handles authentication for a Vue.js and Auth0 application. It stores and retrieves values in local storage. How do I change this code so as to access the values `expiresAt`, `idToken`,  `accessToken` and `user` directly  instead of using local storage?

```
import auth0 from 'auth0-js'
import Vue from 'vue'

let webAuth = new auth0.WebAuth({
domain: 'your_auth0_domain',
clientID: 'your_auth0_client',

redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8080/callback',

audience: 'https://' + 'your_auth0_domain' + '/api/v2/',
responseType: 'token id_token',
scope: 'openid profile' // define the scopes you want to use
})

let auth = new Vue({
computed: {
    token: {
        get: function () {
            return localStorage.getItem('id_token')
        },
        set: function (id_token) {
            localStorage.setItem('id_token', id_token)
        }
    },
    accessToken: {
        get: function () {
            return localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        },
        set: function (accessToken) {
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken)
        }
    },
    expiresAt: {
        get: function () {
            return localStorage.getItem('expires_at')
        },
        set: function (expiresIn) {
            let expiresAt = JSON.stringify(expiresIn * 1000 + new Date().getTime())
            localStorage.setItem('expires_at', expiresAt)
        }
    },
    user: {
        get: function () {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
        },
        set: function (user) {
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
        }
    }
},
methods: {
    login() {
        webAuth.authorize()
    },
    logout() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
            localStorage.removeItem('id_token')
            localStorage.removeItem('expires_at')
            localStorage.removeItem('user')
            webAuth.authorize()

        })
    },
    isAuthenticated() {
        return new Date().getTime() < this.expiresAt
    },
    handleAuthentication() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            webAuth.parseHash((err, authResult) => {

                if (authResult && authResult.accessToken && authResult.idToken) {
                    this.expiresAt = authResult.expiresIn
                    this.accessToken = authResult.accessToken
                    this.token = authResult.idToken
                    this.user = authResult.idTokenPayload

                    resolve()


                } else if (err) {
                    this.logout()
                    reject(err)
                }

            })
        })
    }
}
})

export default {
install: function (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$auth = auth
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) store

Once you get the token from the end point you can store it to local storage:

```
api_call_here
.then(response => {
  localStorage.setItem('token', response.body.token)
})
```

Next, your vuex store should look like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
    isLogged: !!localStorage.getItem('token')
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || null
}
```

In that way you will be able in every component to check if user is logged by:

`this.$store.state.isLogged` //=> will return true or false

You can follow the same logic for access token and expires at.

**Update:** The SPA applications can handle everything without need of refresh. But after reload (manually) the variables will not hold their own state.

That's why you are using local Storage, so even if the page reloads the token is saved in local Storage and you can retrieve it.

Practically when the user logs in, you save the token in localStorage.Whenever
the page reloads, the user stays logged until the token is in localStorage.

If you just put the token in a variable, if the page reloads this variable will not hold the token anymore.

If you don't like the localStorage, as solution, you can send a login request whenever the page reloads which is not recommended.

I want to mention that you can also use cookies.

Hope my answer helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look into vuex. However it seems you misunderstood my question. What I want to achieve is to avoid using local storage altogether and directly access the variables

Comment: Oh you don't want to use localStorage at all? So you can save the token directly in vuex store without store it in local storage. But you have to wary that when the page reloads the token variable will be empty again. So that's why we use local storage to keep the token even if the page reloads

Comment: I updated my answer. Check if you find something useful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks this was very helpful. I will consider the options you mentioned in the update of your answer